# HTML select multiple values from styled list with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I have a django project with a list of users that I want to include in a post request. Note that only the users that I have checked should be included in the post request in the django function based view.

I wonder how I can get the value of the checked users into the django post request function based view?

Its not exactly like in this picture but the checkbox and the user part Is the same, I couldn't find out how to put a local file into stack overflow!

[image]

The Project Page:

```
@login_required
def projectPage(request):
    obj = Project.objects.filter(canview__user=request.user)
    assignments = Assignment.objects.filter(canview__user=request.user)
    allstudents = UserProfile.objects.all()
    username = request.user
    context = {
        'object': obj,
        'MyName': username,
        'Assignments': assignments,
        'students': allstudents
    }
    return render(request, 'allProjects.html', context)
```

The POST REQUEST Page:

```
@login_required
def create_project(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        name = request.POST.get('Project-Name')
        description = request.POST.get('Project-Description') 
        parent_assignment = Assignment.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('Project-ParentAssignmentID'))

        membersInProject == SOMETHING

        project = Project(name=name, description=description, parent_assignment=parent_assignment, members = membersInProject)


        project.save()

        return redirect('allaStudieplaner')
```

In The HTML template:

```
{% for student in students %}
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">

                            <span class="d-flex align-items-center">


                                <div style="margin-right: 10px">
                                    <div class="circle">
                                        <span class="initials" , style="color: #ffffff"> {{ elev.user|capfirst|first }}
                                        </span>
                                      </div>
                                </div>

                              <div style="width: 300px">

                                <span class="h6 mb-0" data-filter-by="text">{{elev.user|capfirst}}</span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="checkboxx"> <input type="checkbox" unchecked>
                                <style>
                                .checkerName {
                                  margin-left: 10px
                                }

                                .checkboxx {
                                  align-content: flex-end;
                                  margin-left: 300px
                                }
                                </style> </div>

                            </span>
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Input attributes

You need to be able to read the `name` of the field in your django file. Do this by adding a `name` attribute to the `input type="checkbox"` element.

Then you'll want to know which *student* is associated with that checkbox. Do this by adding some data of the student in the `value` attribute of the checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="students[]" value="{{ student.name }}">
```

Notice the `students[]` instead of just `students`? This is because multiple checkboxes of students should be able to be checked. And by using the `[]` after the name makes sure that the checkbox values will be sent in an `array` which each checked `input` value included. Otherwise you would simply overwrite each `students` in a single value.

## The Form

When you want to submit something to the server (with or without JS) you need the `form` element. This `form` element needs to be wrapped around the `input` elements so that the values of the `input` elements are part of the `form`.

Specify the `action` and `method` attributes on the `form` element to indicate *where* the request has to be sent to and *what* method it should use to do that.

Now you also need a way to trigger the `form` for submission. You could do that in JS but for now i'll just use HTML to show it.

Add an `input type="submit"` or `button type="submit"`, the latter is more suitable for styling, and add that in the form. Usually it goes at the end to indicate that there are no more fields to fill in and the next step is submitting.

```
<form id="create-project-form" action="create_project" method="POST">
    {% for student in students %}
       ...
       ...
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Send the form</button>
</form>
```

## Fetch and XMLHTTPRequest

**Note: I am unable to test this and don't have Django experience, so this will be a guide to just setup the JS side based on what I could find in examples.**

There are two ways to send values to the server in JavaScript. [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). The former is the latest technology in sending HTTPRequest to the server while the latter is supported on legacy browsers.
So in this case we'll use **Fetch**.

First we create the function which will send the data using `fetch`. This function takes `url` and `data` parameters. `url` being the place where we send the request to and `data` the values that has to be send.

```
function postForm(url, data) {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',           // Sending as POST
        body: data,               // Include the data 
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',  // Tell the server what kind of data to expect.
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'    // Tell the server that this is a XMLHttpRequest. Django needs this.
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {              // Check if request has succeeded.
            return response.text();                 // If so return the response in a string.
        }
        throw new Error(response.status);           // Else throw an error.
    }).catch((error) => {                           // catch is called whenever an error occurs. 
        console.log(error);                         // Show the error.
    });
};
```

Great, the `fetch` function is in place. Now we continue to the function which should get the data from the form and send the request.

Here below I've created the `submitCreateProjectForm` function. It will be hooked to the `submit` event and should only be called whenever the form is submitted. The `event` parameter will give us information about *what* the event is and *which* form has been submitted.

Then we can store the data of the form in a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) instance. `FormData` will get all the `names` and `values` of the `input` elements from the form and store it.

And after you got the names and values send the request to the server using the `fetch` function we just created.

```
function submitCreateProjectForm(event) {
    const form = event.target;            // The form that has been submitted
    const data = new FormData(form);      // Extract the data from the form
    const url = '/destinationtosendto/';  // Define your url to send the form data to.
    postForm(url, data);                  // And send!
    event.preventDefault();               // Stop form from default behavior so the page won't reload.
};
```

You'll want to send something whenever a user *submits* the form. So listen to the `submit` event on the form that we've made.

```
const form = document.getElementById('create-project-form');   // Get the form element.
if (form !== null) {                                           // Check if the form element has been found.
    form.addEventListener('submit', submitCreateProjectForm)   // If so then add an event listener to it. In this case listen for submit.
}
```

This should send a request to the server whenever the form has been submitted. Now I don't know the URL to send the data to since I haven't ever used Django and don't know the `endpoints` of your project. So that will be for you to figure out.

Best of luck and have a nice day!

Comment: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use students.set() instead.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I get that error when I tried your code out :) Thanks a lot for helping btw!

Comment: Glad to help. I've never worked with Django before so it's a learning experience form me as well. After doing some research I discovered that we have to implement some more steps to Django to process information of a `form`. Check out these links [MDN Django Form Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms) and [Working with forms | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/). If you really want to use the HTMLRequest, we could modify the code with some JavaScript. Read up on these links and try them out.

Comment: thanks, could you show me how we would approach this using some javascript?

Comment: I've added a small tutorial about setting up the JavaScript part of your form. I do have to point out that this is no guarantee that it will work since you still need to make modifications on the Django side to properly receive the HTTPRequest. I hope you can figure that out.

Comment: Thanks man, so you mean just put this in a javascript file that triggers when I press the submit button? And where do I pass in the context?

Comment: Yes, put this in a `.js` file and add the file to the same page as the form. What do you mean with "the context"?

Comment: The context is here `const data = new FormData(form);` This will create an object which will be send to the server based on the `input` elements in your form. For now it will only consist of the `students` since those are the only `input` elements that are in your form. Add more `input` elements to send more values.

Comment: name = request.POST.get('Studyplan-Name')
        description = request.POST.get('Studyplan-Description') 
        parent_assignment = Assignment.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('Studyplan-PAID'))
        students = request.POST.get('students')
        studyplan = Studyplan(name=name, description=description, parent_assignment=parent_assignment, students=students)
        studyplan.save()

Comment: Add more inputs like this:
`<input type="hidden" name="Studyplan-Name" value="Name of your studyplan"/>`

Comment: I'm originally an app developer, so all this is kinda new, and I'm way to inexperienced to be able to put all this together with javascript. Is there any way you could put it together also with the post view and the html?

Comment: Ah, welcome to the web! I'm afraid not. I'm here to help answer some questions or guide you in the right direction, but I can't build your project. And I've never used Django. I suggest you do some research and look for as many tutorials as you can find. Or get help from somebody who does have experience with the kind of project you are building. Best of luck!